# How to save camera captured image with custom file name in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I am trying to take a picture from camera in Android and I want to save it with a custom file name using UUID (eg: f12b5700-1d92-11e9-ab14-d663bd873d93.jpg).

In the following code, in `onActivityResult`, I do get the **f12b5700-1d92-11e9-ab14-d663bd873d93.jpg** in photoPath but when I check the actual image on device, it is saved as timestamp.jpg (eg: 1548082653944.jpg). My question is how can I make the image to be saved with custom name?

```
private var photoURI: Uri? = null
private fun takePhoto()
    {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg")

        photoURI = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
        {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

in onActivityResult handler, the code looks like this:

```
if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE)
{
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE)

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(photoURI!!, proj, null, null, null)
        val index = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE)

        cursor.moveToFirst()
        photoPath = cursor.getString(index)
        cursor.close()

         Toast.makeText(this, photoPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    else
    {
        capturedImage.setImageURI(null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Photo was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean it is literally being saved `timestamp.jpg` or it's being saved as `2019-01-21T15:35.jpg` (or similar)?

Comment: It is saved as 1548082653944.jpg

Comment: Does the same apply for `uuid.jpg`..? Please make your question clear!

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the question. I want to save it as for example: f12b5700-1d92-11e9-ab14-d663bd873d93.jpg

Comment: Replace the `ContentValues` and `contentResolver.insert()` stuff with `FileProvider`. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/Camera/FileProvider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some struggle, I was able to solve the problem with the help of CommonsWare link:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/Camera/FileProvider

Additionally I took help from these links:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#sharing-files-with-api-24-or-higher

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState(java.io.File)

The trick is to use FileProvider.
I had to add `<provider>` in AndroidManifest.xml

Working code looks like this:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Storage is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }

        var imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg"
        var output = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(appName), imageName)


        if (!output.parentFile.exists() && !output.parentFile.mkdir())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to create storage folder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }

        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, output)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
        {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
```

Provider:

```
<provider
    android:authorities="com.domain.appname.fileprovider"
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="appname" path="appname" />
</paths>
```

Change com.domain.appname and appname accordingly.

Comment: What is the value of authority?